# Import hooks for PyQt4.QtCore

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, python-sip

I'm am attempting to setup some [import hooks](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-hooks) through `sys.meta_path`, in a somewhat similar approach to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268643/package-specific-import-hooks-in-python). For this, I need to define two functions `find_module` and `load_module` as explained in the link above. Here is my `load_module` function,

```
import imp

def load_module(name, path):
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module(name, path)

    try:
        module = imp.load_module(name, fp, pathname, description)
    finally:
        if fp:
             fp.close()
    return module
```

which works fine for most modules, but fails for `PyQt4.QtCore` when using Python 2.7:

```
name = "QtCore"
path = ['/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4']

mod = load_module(name, path)
```

which returns,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
   mod = load_module(name, path)
   File "test.py", line 13, in load_module
   module = imp.load_module(name, fp, pathname, description)
SystemError: dynamic module not initialized properly
```

The same code works fine with Python 3.4 (although [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/imp.html) is getting deprecated and [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/importlib.html#module-importlib) should ideally be used instead there).

I suppose this has something to do with the SIP dynamic module initialization. Is there anything else I should try with Python 2.7?

Note: this applies both with `PyQt4` and `PyQt5`.

**Edit**: this may be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856515/python-import-failed-for-pyqt4) as indeed,

```
cd /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4
python2 -c 'import QtCore'
```

fails with the same error. Still I'm not sure what would be a way around it...

**Edit2**: following **@Nikita**'s request for a concrete use case example, what I am trying to do is to redirect the import, so when one does `import A`, what happens is `import B`. One could indeed think that for this it would be sufficient to do module renaming in `find_spec/find_module` and then use the default `load_module`. However, it is unclear where to find a default `load_module` implementation in Python 2. The closest implementation I have found of something similar is [`future.standard_library.RenameImport`](https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future/blob/master/src/future/standard_library/__init__.py#L232). It does not look like there is a backport of the complete implementation of `importlib` from Python 3 to 2.

A minimal working example for the import hooks that reproduces this problem can be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/rth/69a5bbda069d1e735d57c1052c05e354).

Comment: If it may be useful, to give some general context for what I'm trying to do, see the [SiQt](https://github.com/rth/SiQt) package, and this problem is discussed in [this github issue](https://github.com/rth/SiQt/issues/4).

Comment: i really don't understand your problem but what's wrong with `__import__('PyQt4.QtCore')`. does it lead to infinite recursion?

Comment: @danidee Nothing is wrong with `__import__('A')`, but it is equivalent to using `import A`. What I want is to change what happens when you do that, and in particular run `import B`, when you `import A`. This can be done with import hooks in `sys.meta_path`, but they require lower level functions such as `imp.load_module`.

Comment: @rth, indeed in the docs about `imporylib` in Python 2.7 it's written: _"This module is a minor subset of what is available in the more full-featured package of the same name from Python 3.1 that provides a complete implementation of import."_. There're thoughts about custom imports in [PEP302](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/), I'll look at it and share my thoughts in the answer update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***UPD: This part in not really relevant after answer updates, so see UPD below.***

Why not just use [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html?highlight=imp#importlib.import_module), which is available in both Python 2.7 and Python 3:

```
#test.py

import importlib

mod = importlib.import_module('PyQt4.QtCore')
print(mod.__file__)
```

on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
$ python2 test.py 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so
```

Since it's a dynamic module, as said in the error (and the actual file is `QtCore.so`), may be also take a look at [`imp.load_dynamic`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html?highlight=imp#imp.load_dynamic).

Another solution might be to force the execution of the module initialization code, but IMO it's too much of a hassle, so why not just use `importlib`.

**UPD**: There are things in `pkgutil`, that might help. What I was talking about in my comment, try to modify your finder like this:

```
import pkgutil

class RenameImportFinder(object):

    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        """ This is the finder function that renames all imports like
             PyQt4.module or PySide.module into PyQt4.module """
        for backend_name in valid_backends:
            if fullname.startswith(backend_name):
                # just rename the import (That's what i thought about)
                name_new = fullname.replace(backend_name, redirect_to_backend)
                print('Renaming import:', fullname, '->', name_new, )
                print('   Path:', path)


                # (And here, don't create a custom loader, get one from the
                # system, either by using 'pkgutil.get_loader' as suggested
                # in PEP302, or instantiate 'pkgutil.ImpLoader').

                return pkgutil.get_loader(name_new) 

                #(Original return statement, probably 'pkgutil.ImpLoader'
                #instantiation should be inside 'RenameImportLoader' after
                #'find_module()' call.)
                #return RenameImportLoader(name_orig=fullname, path=path,
                #       name_new=name_new)

    return None
```

Can't test the code above now, so please try it yourself.

P.S. Note that `imp.load_module()`, which worked for you in Python 3 is [deprecated since Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/imp.html#imp.load_module).

Another solution is not to use hooks at all, but instead wrap the `__import__`:

```
print(__import__)

valid_backends = ['shelve']
redirect_to_backend = 'pickle'

# Using closure with parameters 
def import_wrapper(valid_backends, redirect_to_backend):
    def wrapper(import_orig):
        def import_mod(*args, **kwargs):
            fullname = args[0]
            for backend_name in valid_backends:
                if fullname.startswith(backend_name):
                    fullname = fullname.replace(backend_name, redirect_to_backend)
                    args = (fullname,) + args[1:]
            return import_orig(*args, **kwargs)
        return import_mod
    return wrapper

# Here it's important to assign to __import__ in __builtin__ and not
# local __import__, or it won't affect the import statement.
import __builtin__
__builtin__.__import__ = import_wrapper(valid_backends, 
                                        redirect_to_backend)(__builtin__.__import__)

print(__import__)

import shutil
import shelve
import re
import glob

print shutil.__file__
print shelve.__file__
print re.__file__
print glob.__file__
```

output:

```
<built-in function __import__>
<function import_mod at 0x02BBCAF0>
C:\Python27\lib\shutil.pyc
C:\Python27\lib\pickle.pyc
C:\Python27\lib\re.pyc
C:\Python27\lib\glob.pyc
```

`shelve` renamed to `pickle`, and `pickle` is imported by default machinery with the variable name `shelve`.

Comment: I agree with your two first ideas, unfortunately they do not work, I have tried it before. a) As far as I understand, `importlib.import_module` is too high level to put in a `sys.meta_path` import hooks. What happens is when you import a package it will look in `sys.meta_path`, and if the `load_module` function uses `importlib.import_module` it will look in `sys.meta_path` again where it will find the same `load_module` function etc, so you get an infinite recursion problem...  What is needed is something of lower lever such as `imp.find_module` or `importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader

Comment: b) I have tried `imp.load_dynamic`, it produces the same result (since it must be called by `imp.load_module` I suppose). c) Yes, I know I'd rather not initialize that module by hand.  What I don't understand is why I have to (i.e. what operation `importlib.import_module` does and `imp.load_module` doesn't, that make this necessary). The same is true for all PyQt4/PyQt4 submodules. What I'm trying to achieve is import `SiQt.QtCore` when `PyQt4.QtCore`is imported. I know this is possible since  python future.standard_library.RenameImport does it in PY2 (essentially it's just import renaming).

Comment: @rth, by the link you provided about import hooks, it says that the meta path finder will call `find_spec`/`find_module` recursively for each part of the path. E.g. `mpf.find_spec("PyQt4", None, None)` and then one more `mpf.find_spec("PyQt4.QtCore", PyQt4.__path__, None)`. So if you're hooking in place of `find_spec` or in some other part of mpf, may be replace `PyQt4` with `SiQt` in the name string and then call the default machinery to let it load `SiQt` by itself. If I'm wrong, please, provide some code used for hooks to better understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I agree that using the default  machinery for `load_module` would have been nice. See Edit2 in the question above.

Comment: @rth, if hooks won't work, you can wrap the `__import__`, check out the answer update.

Answer (score 3):

When finding a module which is part of package like `PyQt4.QtCore`, you have to recursively find each part of the name without `.`. And `imp.load_module` requires its `name` parameter be full module name with `.` separating package and module name.

Because `QtCore` is part of a package, you shoud do `python -c 'import PyQt4.QtCore'` instead. Here's the code to load a module.

```
import imp

def load_module(name):
    def _load_module(name, pkg=None, path=None):
        rest = None
        if '.' in name:
            name, rest = name.split('.', 1)
        find = imp.find_module(name, path)
        if pkg is not None:
            name = '{}.{}'.format(pkg, name)
        try:
            mod = imp.load_module(name, *find)
        finally:
            if find[0]:
                find[0].close()
        if rest is None:
            return mod 
        return _load_module(rest, name, mod.__path__)
    return _load_module(name)
```

Test;

```
print(load_module('PyQt4.QtCore').qVersion())  
4.8.6
```